# Nginx how to serve text files with a “Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8” header?

Tags: nginx

How can I serve text (`.txt`) files with header `Content-Type: text/plain; Charset=UTF-8` in Nginx?

I have a nginx/1.18.0 running on Ubuntu 20.04, and in `nginx.conf` I have this set:

```
http {
(...)
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

And in `mime.types` I have this:

```
types {
(...)
    text/plain                            txt;
```

But when I access text files, it's served with these headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
(...)
Content-Type: text/plain
```

But I want to serve it with these headers:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please look at [this answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/312177/100013). That said, are you sure you reloaded and restarted Nginx after adjusting your config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you want is this:

```
charset utf-8;
```

Comment: that worked, thanks! ```Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8```